# Replace File in Gradle Build

Tags: java, groovy, gradle, build

I am trying to replace a file in my resource folder (src/main/resources) with a new file generated by the Gradle build script.  I'm having trouble doing this; the exclusion seems to be remembered, and preventing the addition of my new file.

Here's a short example that illustrates the behavior.

Project Structure:

```
TestProject
-- src/main/java
---- entry
------ EntryPoint.java
---- run
------ HelloWorldTest.java
-- src/main/resources
---- test.properties // FILE TO REPLACE
```

test.properties contents in src/main/resources:

`Wrong File with extra text to make it obvious which one is being put into the jar based on size`

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

task makeProp {
    def propDir = new File(buildDir, "props")
    ext.propFile = new File(propDir, "test.properties")
    outputs.file propFile

    doLast {
        propDir.mkdirs()
        propFile.createNewFile()
        propFile.withWriter('utf-8') { writer ->
            writer.writeLine 'Right File'
        }
    }
}

jar {
    dependsOn('makeProp')

    if (project.hasProperty('testExclude')) {
        sourceSets {
            exclude('test.properties')
        }
    }

    from (makeProp.propFile) {
        into '/'
    }
}
```

JAR contents of `./gradlew build` (both files included):

```
Archive:  TestProject.jar
  Length     Date   Time    Name
 --------    ----   ----    ----
        0  08-07-15 14:27   META-INF/
       25  08-07-15 14:27   META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
        0  08-07-15 13:50   run/
      499  08-07-15 13:50   run/HelloWorldTest.class
        0  08-07-15 13:50   entry/
     1413  08-07-15 13:50   entry/EntryPoint.class
       95  08-07-15 14:27   test.properties
       11  08-07-15 14:03   test.properties
 --------                   -------
     2043                   8 files
```

JAR contents of `./gradlew build -PtestExclude` (neither file included):

```
Archive:  TestProject.jar
  Length     Date   Time    Name
 --------    ----   ----    ----
        0  08-07-15 14:29   META-INF/
       25  08-07-15 14:29   META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
        0  08-07-15 13:50   run/
      499  08-07-15 13:50   run/HelloWorldTest.class
        0  08-07-15 13:50   entry/
     1413  08-07-15 13:50   entry/EntryPoint.class
 --------                   -------
     1937                   6 files
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have done something very similar and this is what worked for me. The main objective is to make sure the task runs before your jar is created and your files are processed. Try this out.

```
    // create a properties file add it to folder preprocessing
    task propertiesFile << {
        // 
        description 'Dynamically creates a properties file.'

        // needed for the first pass
        def folder = project.file('src/main/resources');
        if(!folder.exists()){
            folder.mkdirs()
        }

        //write it to a propertiess file
        def props = project.file('src/main/resources/test.properties')
        props.delete()
        props << 'write this to my file!!!!'

    }

    processResources.dependsOn propertiesFile
```

Comment: I ended up doing something similar to this.  I've accepted this as the answer, with my own to follow.  I was hoping there would be a more direct solution than having to basically work around their exclusion mechanism, but I'm sure that there must be some rational reason for the mechanism working the way it does that a build novice like me can't think of.

Answer (score 2):

The solution I went with in the end was similar to what was posted by Pumphouse, but instead of deleting the file, I renamed it to a temp name, excluded that temp name, and renamed it once I was done (I needed to preserve the file contents and position after the build was complete).

Modified build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

def props = project.file('src/main/resources/test.properties')
def temp = project.file('src/main/resources/temp.properties')

task makeProp {
    ... // Unchanged
}

jar {
    dependsOn('makeProp')

    // Move the properties file to a temp location
    props.renameTo(temp) // This returns a boolean; can perform conditional checks.

    // Exclude the temp file
    if (project.hasProperty('testExclude')) {
        sourceSets {
            exclude('temp.properties')
        }
    }

    // Insert the right prop file
    from (makeProp.propFile) {
        into '/'
    }
}
jar << {
    // Restore the temp file
    temp.renameTo(props)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The thing is that the exclusion patterns for the gradle [SourceSet](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.SourceSet.html) apply to all included paths and not only to specific paths. Therefore in your example above all files named `test.properties` will be excluded, regardless on their location.

What you can do is to have the default `test.properties` located somewhere else and make the build copy/generate the relevant version based on the scenario.